# number field in lighting-datatable being saved as a string

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a `lighting-datatable` in an LWC component with a number field, but every time I save the changes in the table, the field is being updated as a string.

Here is my html:

```
<lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns} onsave={saveHandleAction}
            draft-values={fldsItemValues} hide-checkbox-column show-row-number-column>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

and here is my js class:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

const columns = [
    { label: 'My number field', fieldName: 'numberField', type: 'number', editable: true },
];

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;
    rowOffset = 0;
    draftValues = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        this.data = [{
          numberField: 2
        }]
    }

    saveHandleAction(event)
    {
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail)))
    }
}
```

If you make a change to the `numberField` and then save, you can see in the console update for `numberField` is a string instead of a number, e.g.:

```
0: Object { }
numberField: "7"
Id: "row-0"
```

[Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/JclGBLkYes2wtoQtRUCF/src/child.js?p=stories)